# How to select same table fields in multiple left join on same table with different alias

Tags: sql-server

Sharing my issue here and any kind of help will be heartily appreciated.

I have a table called 'demandset'. This table do have two columns which I have to use is 'DSTSiteLocationID' and 'DSTTermSiteLocationID'. There is another table called DemandSet_ADDRESS_Mapping and this table have a columns called DAMapID. I am putting left join twice on DemandSet_ADDRESS_Mapping, one for DSTSiteLocationID (alias DSAM1) and another one for DSTTermSiteLocationID (alias DSAM2) with table demandset. Now the table DemandSet_ADDRESS_Mapping have columns DAStreet, DACity, DAState, DAZip which I am selecting in my select statement. But, I am selecting it twice with the alias DSAM1 and DSAM2 as it will return different data when joined with DSTSiteLocationID and DSTTermSiteLocationID. Sharing the code as well.

```
select 
DSAM1.DAStreet 
,DSAM1.DACity 
,DSAM1.DAState 
,DSAM1.DAZip 
,DSAM2.DAStreet 
,DSAM2.DACity 
,DSAM2.DAState 
,DSAM2.DAZip 

FROM   [dbo].[bma30_demandset] BDS (nolock) 

               LEFT JOIN BMA30_DemandSet_ADDRESS_Mapping DSAM1 (NOLOCK) ON ISNULL(DSAM1.DAMapID,'') = ISNULL(BDS.DSTSiteLocationID,'') 
               LEFT JOIN BMA30_DemandSet_ADDRESS_Mapping DSAM2 (NOLOCK) ON ISNULL(DSAM2.DAMapID,'') = ISNULL(BDS.DSTTermSiteLocationID,'')
```

I am getting the below error message for all the fields.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Procedure BMA30_FN_DemandSet_CHART_PIVOT_Insert, Line 146
The column 'DAStreet' was specified multiple times for 'A'.

As per the error message it is not allowing me to use the column twice even I have used two different alias.

Comment: You shouldn't use NOLOCK hint unless you genuinely do not care if the data is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to use an alias for your column name in time of selection

```
select 
 DSAM1.DAStreet 
,DSAM1.DACity 
,DSAM1.DAState 
,DSAM1.DAZip 
,DSAM2.DAStreet as DSAM2_DAStreet
,DSAM2.DACity as DSAM2_DACity
,DSAM2.DAState as DSAM2_DAState
,DSAM2.DAZip  as DSAM2_DAZip
FROM   [dbo].[bma30_demandset] BDS (nolock) 
LEFT JOIN BMA30_DemandSet_ADDRESS_Mapping DSAM1 (NOLOCK) ON ISNULL(DSAM1.DAMapID,'') = ISNULL(BDS.DSTSiteLocationID,'') 
LEFT JOIN BMA30_DemandSet_ADDRESS_Mapping DSAM2 (NOLOCK) ON ISNULL(DSAM2.DAMapID,'') = ISNULL(BDS.DSTTermSiteLocationID,'')
```

Comment: I would say _"You've to use an alias"_ instead of _"You've to rename"_.